# Order of 'static' function keyword vs return type specifier in C

Tags: c, static-methods, static-functions

Hopefully this is not a duplicate of a number of other questions relating to the meaning of 'static' functions in C.

We support some legacy native C code containing things along the following lines ... (don't ask me why re VOID/void)

```
#define VOID void
#define LOCAL static
...
VOID LOCAL vLoMyMethod();
```

Presumably the pre-processor translates the latter to

```
void static vLoMyMethod();
```

The compiler (Visual Studio 2015, presumably relatively vanilla flags/settings, warning level W3) seems fine with this, even though my reading is that 'static' should come before the return type specifier, i.e.

```
static void vLoMyMethod();
```

Are these syntactically equivalent and both correct? If not, why is the compiler accepting the former possibly incorrect syntax?

**Edit 1**

Thanks for answers so far.  Interestingly, I'm not sure they're 100% equivalent and both acceptable in all scenarios, ala:

```
char * static vLoMyMethod1();   // compiler complains about expecting 'type' (intellisense wants an identifier)
static char * vLoMyMethod2();   // compiler is fine
```

Comment: I'm kinda amazed I couldn't find a duplicate...

Comment: As near as I can tell from the grammar and footnotes of `storage-class-specifier` and `declaration-specifiers` in the C11 draft standard this reordering is valid. Curiously even `int typedef X;` would appear to be a valid declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the ordering is free in C89, C99 and C11. However [C11 6.11.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5) says that w.r.t. `static` it is an obsolescent feature:

> 1 The placement of a **storage-class specifier** other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

The ordering is much freer than is generally thought but you shouldn't be (ab)using it. For example this abomination is [a valid declaration](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.2) in C11 too:

```
_Alignas(double) volatile long int long unsigned const static *(*(*(a)));
```

Though better written as something like

```
static volatile const unsigned long long int _Alignas(double) ***a;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard, both versions are fine:

**n1570 (latest C11 draft) §6.7:**

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list (opt);
    static_assert-declaration

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers (opt)
    type-specifier declaration-specifiers (opt)
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers (opt)
    function-specifier declaration-specifiers (opt)
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers (opt)
```

So, any declaration specifier might be followed by any other declaration specifier.

But beware that a storage-class specifier **should** be placed at the beginning:

**n1570 §6.11.5:**

> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

Therefore, future standards might render

```
void static vLoMyMethod();
```

invalid.